# How to construct Model in MVC - swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, model, property-observer

I'm confused, in MVC [image: MVC]

model should never talk with the `view`, but so far I've always seen project that work in this way:

1- `Controller` creates model object from database, stores it somewhere (array, dictionary, variables)

2- `Controller` updates the `view` accordingly, even using delegate methods f.i. in collectionViews.

My question is this: does the model need to represent perfectly what's going to be displayed by the view? So that I can pass the model object to the view and set the view according to it?

So far I've always implemented this procedure but I'd like to know if there's something wrong with this approach.

Example to be clear, in `controller`:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCollectionviewCell
    cell.currentItem = self.posts[indexPath.item] as? Post 
    return cell
}
```

In `view` using `property observer`:

```
   var currentItem :Post?{
    didSet{
            guard let thumbnailUrlString = self.currentItem?.thumbnailUrl else { return }
            self.imageview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: thumbnailUrlString))
            bottomLayer.isHidden = true
            
        }
    
}
```

Comment: IMO the "Controller creates model object from database, stores it somewhere" is a minimal solution, which almost never works in real life, because it means you are going to backend _every time the Controller is recreated_. Or you are also dumping some caching inside your view controller. In the end you have a monster. And then you want to add another view controller (say, displaying details), and you need to repeat the effort, or need to pass the data back and forth between various controllers.

Comment: A much better choice would be to separate "create model to display", which is a view controller job, from "retrieve object from database, stores it somewhere", which could be some sort of service, which all controllers could access, grab the data they need, and create models suitable for them. And that answers your question too: "service" will have data in its raw form - as retrieved from database and as cached. While "controller" will have only data relevant for current state of the view, in the form that is most easy for view to consume.

Comment: Thank you @KirilS. , with "some sort of service" you mean Firestore extensions (according that I'm using Firebase as backend)?

Comment: I was thinking more about Service Layer (https://emacsway.github.io/en/service-layer/), but sure you can start from just simple Data Sources, and let them evolve into service layer if needed. The main point is that you separate "data you retrieve" from "data you display" early in design, and let those 2 parts communicate in only well defined protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> does the model need to represent perfectly what's going to be displayed by the view?

Yes, a model is, by definition, a representation of what is really going to be displayed.

> So that I can pass the model object to the view and set the view according to it?

You can, but not necessarily do so. It's your call. This idea (of passing model object to view) is certainly a convenient pattern. For trivial apps, that’s fine.

The problem is that your views become entangled with the model. Instead, you might want to think of your view as something that is a little more abstract, designed, for example, to show lists of things that consist of an image and a text string. Then that view could be used for showing any list of things consisting of image and title.

At a minimum, you might define views to use protocols (e.g. a protocol for things that can be shown in a list), rather referring to concrete model types. Or give your cell a simple `configure(image:text:)` method, and let the controller dictate what model properties are to be used.

Regardless, I would advise against storing a copy of a model object in a collection view cell. It only introduces confusion: If your UI allows you to edit the object, are you editing this copy in the cell, or the model? Theoretically, you can propagate changes with observers, but it can get confusing, and it is unnecessary here.

---

I get the impression that you might be thinking of the view controller as the MVC “controller”. Instead, many think of it more of part of the MVC “view”, as it fundamentally is all about preparing and populating views, reacting to user input,  and responding to UI events. Many of us create more abstract “controllers” (or presenters or view models), something not tied to UIKit (or whatever). This also has the merit of letting us write unit tests for business logic, completely independent of the UI.

Here are a few links that rethink what MVC means and/or consider some logical alternatives:

- See Dave Delong’s [A Better MVC](https://youtu.be/YWVzCd5FYbs) for a perspective of embracing MVC but employing techniques to keep them small and manageable.
- See Medium’s [iOS Architecture Patterns](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52) for a review of other approaches ranging from MVP, MVVM, Viper, etc.
- See Krzysztof Zabłocki’s [iOS Application Architecture](https://youtu.be/PdkWjdKOqfo) for another good discussion on the topic.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to understand more the part in which you say “you might define views to use protocols”. In what way are they supposed to use protocols?

Comment: You can use a protocol to capture the essence of what is needed. E.g., you might have the list view use a protocol like `protocol Listable { var imageURL: URL { get }; var title: String { get } }`. Then your view can now work with any `Listable` type that has `imageURL` and a `title`  rather than only a `Post`. In general, when writing an interface, always ask yourself whether it really needs to work with a particular concrete type, or whether there is some abstraction that could offer greater reuse opportunities.